# Find the lengths of sides of a right triangle

Tags: triangles

If I know the length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle ONLY, is it possible to find the lengths of the remaining 2 sides of that same triangle?

Comment: No.  Any right triangle can be scaled to have any desired hypotenuse.

Comment: oh, okay then,
Any workarounds, maybe?

Comment: Knowing for example that the length of the hypotenuse is $65$, how can you decide for example between sides 39 and 52 or sides 25 and 60 ? Because by Pythagoras $65^2 =39^2 + 52^2$ and $65^2= 25^2 + 60^2$...

Comment: Workaround to what?  Your desired claim simply isn't true.  To be precise, given any angle $0<\theta<\frac {\pi}2$ there is a right triangle with hypotenuse $1$ and legs $\{sin(\theta),\cos(\theta)\}$

Comment: Okay then, just wanted to be sure that there is no way.
Thanks for answers